# Crosstab in Datagrid c#

Tags: c#, sql

is it possible to create crosstab representation of data in data grid. as it is working fine with crystal reports but my requirements are to show crosstab in data grid of windows control.

Comment: I think it is possible only if you get the data from sql already pivotted and you set datagrid to Autogeneratecolumns = true

Comment: i am getting the data from the service and it would be somewhat difficult for me to query the table directly.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [PIVOT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) and get the data already organized the way you want it.

To render this on the form you might have to resort to a 3rd party control like Telerik or the [UltraWinGrid from Infragistics](http://blogs.infragistics.com/forums/p/37083/214714.aspx).

Comment: I cant use 3rd party control because my application doesn`t allow me to use 3rd party controls. one solution is I can use multi dimensional array to make it crosstab. but it would be a lengthy process. I am looking for some effective solution to avoid the complexity

Answer (score 0):

I think you're going to have to pivot the data yourself in order to get the a datasource in the right format.  However, LINQ makes this much easier than it used to be.